# Python library for sending UDS commands over DoIP

Tags: python, robotframework, uds

In one of my projects it is mandatory to send UDS commands using the DoIP protocol. We are using Robot Framework to make some automized test of an ECU of a car prototype. Is there some already existing python library, that allows to send UDS commands over DoIP instead of CAN?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Python-uds](https://python-uds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It was designed to provide a high-level uds interface which can utilize any communication protocol (e.g. LIN, FlexRay, DoIP). It has a parser tool which can parse an ODX file and produce an easy-to-use interface based on the ODX definition.

Comment: I already investigated this library, but couldn't find any point in the sources, where DoIP is somehow implemented. Maybe I will ask the developer of the library.

Comment: I asked, when DoIP will be available: https://github.com/richClubb/python-uds/issues/54

Comment: Can you take a look at this git repo. https://github.com/htkim40/Shiba_DoIP_Tool , this was mentioned in the issue as part of the conversation.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles across this question in the future. DoIP isn't particularly complicated as a transport for UDS. If you're using udsoncan, I've made up a client and adapter that may be useful: https://github.com/jacobschaer/python-doipclient